# How to configure in memory embedded database for mongoDB similar to H2 Database in Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, in-memory-database, embedded-database

I am trying to configure in memory embedded Mongo database with Spring Boot similar to H2 Database. Is there any option available in Spring Mongo?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not have an in-memory storage engine.

You can use tmpfs or zram to create a partition backed by memory and store the data in that partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can create In-memory mongodb-server by using following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.bwaldvogel</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.38.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then declare mongo client in config class

```
@Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
       
    MongoServer server = new MongoServer(new MemoryBackend());
    // bind on a random local port
    InetSocketAddress serverAddress = server.bind();
   return  mongoClient=MongoClients.create(
            MongoClientSettings.builder()
                    .applyToClusterSettings(builder ->
                            builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(serverAddress))))
                    .build());        

    }
```